# SQL - How to get duplicate records from one table with join on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to get records from Table1 where it has more than one record for same Access Number, but at the same time this Access Number should also be present in Table2.

Example

Table1

```
    Access Number

 - 1000
 - 1000
 - 1000
 - 2000
 - 3000
 - 4000
 - 5000
 - 5000
```

Table2

```
AccessNumber  Value

 - 1000       -Value1000
 - 1000       -Value9999
 - 2000       -Value2000
 - 3000       -Value3000
```

> The result of the query should be 1000   - Value1000

This is what I've got so far, please suggest

```
SELECT a.AccessNumber, b.Valuefrom Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b on b.AccessNumber = a.AccessNumber
Group by a.AccessNumber, b.VAlue
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

The problem i am facing is the query returns duplicates from Table2.

```
1000   - Value1000
1000   - Value9999
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What is the `CaseReference` field in `Table2`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SQL Server 12

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio Edited

Comment: I'm not getting any duplicates: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4eade/1

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo Maybe coincidentally that query works for the small sample data given, but is failing on the actual data set.

Comment: I see that you've changed data on `TABLE2` with `Value9999`.

Comment: `The result of the query should be 1000 - Value1000` any reason why `Value1000` over `Value9999`? Because even on its own table, there is no determinant between `1000 - Value1000` and `1000 - Value9999` other than the Value column itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much information as to why `1000 - Value1000` should be the result instead of `1000 - Value9999`, we can just get the first record from the top:

```
select top 1 * from (

-- your original query
SELECT a.AccessNumber, b.Value from Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b on b.AccessNumber = a.AccessNumber
Group by a.AccessNumber, b.Value
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
-- your original query

) as x;
```

If we are just looking for the `AccessNumber` that has duplicate records, you can remove the `b.Value` from the selected columns and remove that as well in the `Group By` clause.

```
SELECT a.AccessNumber from Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b on b.AccessNumber = a.AccessNumber
Group by a.AccessNumber
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3f114/3

Answer (score 1):

We might be able to get this working using SQL Server's `EXCEPT` operator.  But one sensible way to go here would be to just aggregate both tables by access number, and then left join the first to the second, retaining only access numbers which appear in both tables *and* which appear in greater quantity in the first than the second.

```
SELECT t1.AccessNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT AccessNumber, COUNT(*) AS cnt_1
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY AccessNumber
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT AccessNumber, COUNT(*) AS cnt_2
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY AccessNumber
) t2
    ON t1.AccessNumber = t2.AccessNumber
WHERE
    t1.cnt_1 - COALESCE(t2.cnt_2, 0) > 0 AND t2.cnt_2 IS NOT NULL;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I am actually running this on a much larger table but this returns more records than is desired

Comment: @Maverick No, [it works](http://rextester.com/OOCES31663).  Check the demo.

Comment: How do you get the Value column?

Comment: That question doesn't make much sense.  _Which_ value for each access number do you want to select?  You need to talk in terms of aggregates now, because the above report is an aggregate of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

--Hope this query will help you

```
 ; with cte_accessnumber(Accessnumber, [value])
  as
 (
 select 
 t1.Accessnumber, count(*)NoOfRecords
 from table1 t1
 where exists (
 select top 1 1 from table2 t2 where t2.Accessnumber = t1.Accessnumber)
 group by t1.Accessnumber
 having count(*)>1
 )
 select t1.Accessnumber, t2.[value]
 from cte_accessnumber t1
 inner join table2 t2 on t2.Accessnumber = t1.Accessnumber and t2.[value] like '%' + convert(varchar(20),t1.Accessnumber) +'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try using nested for the criteria that AccessNumber rows > 1 and cross apply for criteria which only display 1 record

```
DECLARE @tblA AS TABLE
(
  AccessNumber INT
)
DECLARE @tblB AS TABLE
(
  AccessNumber INT,
  colB NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @tblA SELECT 1000
INSERT INTO @tblA SELECT 1000
INSERT INTO @tblA SELECT 1000
INSERT INTO @tblA SELECT 1000
INSERT INTO @tblA SELECT 2000
INSERT INTO @tblA SELECT 3000
INSERT INTO @tblA SELECT 4000
INSERT INTO @tblB SELECT 1000,'hello'
INSERT INTO @tblB SELECT 1000,'hello2'
INSERT INTO @tblB SELECT 2000,'world'

-- Query --
    SELECT tblB.* FROM (
    SELECT AccessNumber,COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM @tblA GROUP BY AccessNumber ) ftblA 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM @tblB itblB WHERE ftblA.AccessNumber = itblB.AccessNumber) tblB
    WHERE ftblA.cnt >1
-- Only 1000 should be displayed only --
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `subquery` with `correlation` approach

```
select access_no, 
      (select top 1 Value from table2 where access_no = t.access_no) as value
from Table1 t
where exists (
    select 1 from table2 where access_no = t.access_no)
group by access_no
having count(*) > 1
```

However, you would need to specify `order by` clause in `subquery` in order to fetch the value from `table2`